# SEO friendly routing 2 query strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo, url-routing

I am trying SEO Friendly Routing first time and wanted to pass 2 query strings.

Basic Routing was www.SiteName.com/brandName which i did like this

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection Routes)
{
    Routes.MapPageRoute("Brands", "Brands/{brand}", "~/Brand.aspx");
}
```

To create a Product page i wanted to pass two query strings i.e. 
www.SiteName.com/brandName/ProductName

To do so i added this line to my Route Collection

```
    Routes.MapPageRoute("Phones", "{*brand}/{*ProdName}", "~/ProdName.aspx");
```

**PROBLEM:**
The SEO Friendly Routing for product page is working fine but it always give an error when i try to debug .... if I stop debugging then it starts to work again.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at this?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute.aspx

Comment: I followed the msdn link and cant find what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the msdn link and cant find what i did wrong.

**Global.asax**

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection Routes)
{
    //www.Sitename.com/Brand
    Routes.MapPageRoute("Brands", "Brands/{brand}", "~/Brand.aspx");

    //www.Sitename.com/Brand/Productname
    Routes.MapPageRoute("Phones", "{brand}/{*proname}", "~/product.aspx");

}
```

**Product.aspx.cs**

```
        String ProductName = Page.RouteData.Values["Phones"].ToString();
```

**ERROR in Debugging (Visual Web Dev.2010):**
Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Phones is the NAME of the route. Did you try looking for Page.RouteData.Values["proname"]

Comment: Yes i did and its working fine but every time i debug it gives error and when i stop debugging it continues to work fine